# Stop asking me about cookies / multiple, nonstop popups

Tags: bug, websites

When I visit Super User, it asks if I want cookies.  I am using macOS 11 / Safari. This is using the default setting Privacy > Prevent cross-site tracking. Not Private Window.

Then I go through the 5 clicks necessary to say that no, I do not want advertising cookies.

---

But I see this dialog over and over. Several times per day. I am logged in to SO / SU all day. But still the popup continues.

Make it stop.

Comment: "I am logged in to SO / SU all day. But still the popup continues." Not for me it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have some "Internet privacy" software suite or browser extension that is clearing cookies for you?

Comment: Given that decent modern browsers now have a setting to disable cookie popups, you could just turn the darn things off.

Comment: I am using macOS 11 / Safari. This is using the default setting Privacy > Prevent cross-site tracking. Not Private Window.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/131247)